# navigator.share is set on desktop Firefox but doesn't do anything

Tags: firefox, web-share

I have some code like this:

```
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: 'example',
    url: 'http://example.com',
  });
}
```

According to [this documentation for `navigator.share` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share), desktop browsers do not support the Web Share API, and `navigator.share` is undefined in those browsers.

However, when I run this code in desktop Firefox, `navigator.share` is defined and set to a function that doesn't seem to do anything when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is a browser extension that is setting `navigator.share`. Try disabling all your extensions.

In my case, it turned out to be this extension: [Plasma Integration by KDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/plasma-integration/).